# Being asked to update a theme that I don't have

Tags: themes, updates

In the Updates page I can see

> kava
>
> You have version installed. Update to 2.1.0.

[image]

Thing is, I don't have such theme...

In the Themes page

[image]

and in the themes folder of this WordPress installation

[image]

I ran a Security Check in ManageWP and it shows that no malware or vulnerabilities were found

[image]

Comment: Does WP show any "broken themes" lower on the themes page - or perhaps you are using a multisite install and this theme is not active on the current site?

Comment: No multisite and no "broken themes" lower on the themes page (if that were the case, the theme wouldhave its folder in the server too

Comment: Any hidden files in that directory list - perhaps just a .styles.css ?

Comment: Didn't find any

Comment: Have a look in your WP database > options table for an option called _site_transient_update_themes. If it is there delete it and WordPress would create a new one. You might have that transient corrupted. My only guess!

Comment: @freejack I see in there `OO:8:"stdClass":5:{s:12:"last_checked";i:1607883955;s:7:"checked";a:5:{s:16:"monstroid2-child";s:5:"1.0.0";s:10:"monstroid2";s:5:"1.1.6";s:15:"twentyseventeen";s:3:"2.5";s:12:"twentytwenty";s:3:"1.6";s:15:"twentytwentyone";s:3:"1.0";}s:8:"response";a:1:{s:4:"kava";a:4:{s:5:"theme";s:4:"kava";s:11:"new_version";s:5:"2.1.0";s:3:"url";s:0:"";s:7:"package";s:53:"https://account.crocoblock.com/free-download/kava.zip";}}s:9:"no_update";a:3:{s:15:"twentyseventeen";a:6:` ...

Comment: there's also an option name with `kava-extra-settings`

Comment: @freejack I deleted but it showed up again with kava in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely this is caused by interference between the Elementor plugin and the Monstroid 2.0 theme. As you can see from [its developer's page](https://www.collectiveray.com/monstroid-2) Monstroid comes with a plugin called Kava Extra. This plugin, [now discontinued by its developer](https://crocoblock.com/blog/kava-2-0-theme-for-elementor-when-less-means-more/), contains templates for the Kava Theme, which also depends on Elementor.

I'm not 100% sure how this works, but I would say that the Kava Extra plugin is installing the theme (hence its return after you deleted the database entry). However, for some reason it does not complete the process by registering it for display on the themes page. That may be a bug in Kava. Perhaps either Elementor or Monstroid is doing something to prevent or annul it.

Also, you may not see Kava in your plugin list, because it is bundled with Monstroid and activated by the theme.

Now, should you install the update? I have no idea. This depends on which components of Kava (if any) are used in the Monstroid child theme you have installed. Or maybe some settings in your Elementor plugin make it critical. You may miss out on nothing if you don't update or you could miss an important security update. Backup your site and try...

Comment: I updated it after the backup and then the theme appeared in the Themes folder requiring new update. After updating it, the notification that there's a theme to update remained so I'll just ignore it for now.